# Recover EC2 instance created from AMI of other EBS instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

It rebooted, then won't restart.

Forgive me if I'm short on details - still collecting them. 
It is an EBS image created from an AMI which was created from another EBS image.

The notes at end may provide some insight.

Is this recoverable? because it is an ebs instance, i can try to attach to it via another image, but I'd rather recover the running EBS.. and would like to understand what happened, is happening.

Any other suggestions very welcome.

```
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ...
Done.
Done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ...
Begin: Starting AppArmor profiles ...
chroot: cannot execute /etc/apparmor/initramfs: No such file or directory
Failure: AppArmor profiles failed to load
Done.
init: console-setup main process (2098) terminated with status 1


    %Ginit: plymouth main process (300) killed by SEGV signal

init: plymouth-splash main process (2387) terminated with status 2

cloud-init running: Sun, 25 Jul 2010 17:28:07 -0400. up 5.89 seconds
init: ureadahead-other main process (2449) terminated with status 4

swapon: /dev/sda3: swapon failed: Device or resource busy
mountall: swapon /dev/sda3 [2451] terminated with status 255
mountall: Problem activating swap: /dev/sda3
mountall: Disconnected from Plymouth
init: hwclock-save main process (2464) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: current plan is to mount the ebs drive from a running instance and modify the /etc/fstab... ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was something wrong with /etc/fstab. Basically

1. take a snapshot of broken ebs (as precaution)
2. detatch broken ebs from /dev/sda1 on relevant machine
3. created new ebs from snapshot
4. attached from running server and
5. edited /etc/fstab detached and
6. reattached to original ebs instance at /dev/sda1 (aws gives error but it worked!)

Comment: further, AWS support provided this link http://osdir.com/ml/ec2ubuntu/2010-05/msg00092.html